# Server initiate client response in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a ASP.NET application that has a form, which sends its information to be processed by the backend server. The server though will sometimes need to send information back the frontend client page for confirmation. I want the server thread to sit and wait for the clients response, and then continue when confirmation is received from the client.

I've looked into using ICallbackEventHandler but it won't keep the session like I need with my current design.

Any thoughts on how I need to adjust the design or implement what I am looking for?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Ajax Developpement`, for example you can use `UpdatePanel control`  based on `Triggers`

Link : http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.web.ui.updatepanel.aspx

In your specific case you can use `Update Method`

LInk : http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.web.ui.updatepanel.update.aspx

Comment: This is very useful information, but I do not think it will work for this instance, or perhaps I'm just not seeing how to use it. I need to send information back to the client to review and approve to the server to continue processing where it left off. This solution I do not believe can handle that...though perhaps none can in which I need to find another solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to avoid a complete Postback, you could use a technology like [SignalR](http://signalr.net/) to call a javascript method on the client from the server.